# Django does not install correctly on windows machine

Tags: python, windows, django

In my windows I'm able to install the django by running the python file setup.py install.

But after that, I'm unable to start a project by saying `django-admin.py startproject newsite`. All it gives me is opening a textfile showing the `django-admin.py`!

Show me a way out guys

Comment: Exact duplicate question (with answer):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838645/how-to-make-python-knows-the-path-to-look-for-py-files/4838680#4838680

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for `cmd` is to simply "open" the file, which in the case of `.py` for you is associated with a text editor (me too). Try `python django-admin.py startproject`.

To make it fool proof, locate your python.exe and type in `\path\to\python.exe \path\to\django-admin.py startproject myproject`

Actually, you said it worked for setup.py install so it sounds like you have the python working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add path to python to your system %PATH% variable.
And then run `python django-admin.py startproject newsite`

But first I recommend you to read this:
http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as follows:

- Added this to the end of my User Variable PATH: C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts
- Added a new System Variable PYTHONPATH and set to: c:\Python27\Lib;c:\Python27\Scipts

Be sure that you close all cmd windows and open a new cmd prompt window *after* you've set your new environment variables.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well well ..I was just having the same problem..and the  problem was not related to any path variables.
The Problem was because of the default python viewer wingIDE. I had changed the default opening of python file from IDLE to wing IDE, this was the problem. 
To solve this ..

- click any python file and open its properties and change the "opens with" to IDLE. This should solve the problem if you had installed django according to the instructions from django site. However, the path setting said above are must and inevitable.

...Cheers and happy coding!!